# Mootools: wrap an element with an anchor while using a class selector

Tags: class, mootools, wrapper

This is my first script, in any language, so yes, i am doing something wrong and it is probably something really really stupid.

I want to wrap the H3 below in between an anchor with Mootools.

First, i tested this with a ID instead of a class. This works. Apparently ('id') is good, ('.class') is bad. But for my specific usecase i need to select the element by its class.

HTML:

```
 <h3 class="class">test</h3>
```

Mootools code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {

var test = document.getElements("h3.class");
var myAnchor = new Element('a', {
    href: 'http://www.someurl.com'
});

var myWrapper = myAnchor.wraps('.class');

});
```

I tried to create a var and grab the element here by its class. Yet i am not sure how to call this var inside wrap string.

```
var myWrapper = myAnchor.wraps(test);
```

Now i am stuck. I hope someone can help me out here, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {

    var test = document.getElement("h3.class");
    var myAnchor = new Element('a', {
        href: 'http://www.someurl.com'
    });

    myAnchor.wraps(test);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LmBVq/

notice `document.getElement` (for a single element).

the opposite of wrap is `adopt`. you could do `myAchor.adopt(test);` and then inject it somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and your tips! Now hopefully it will work on the Joomla website i am working on. I first tried this with jQuery and it worked in jsfiddle, but on the site it gave a mootools/jquery conflict. The jQuery was loaded after Mootools so i could not use NoConflict. I decided to use Mootools instead but it is a little bit more tricky to get started with, so again thanks allot!